# PHP Array keeps getting overwritten when I add to it... Why?

Tags: php, arrays

For some reason, whenever I try to add something to my array, it just overwrites the index 0, rather than goingto index 1, 2 etc...

Here's my code

```
//Saved names
    session_start();
    $saved_names = array();

    $_SESSION['saved_names'] = $saved_names;

    if($_GET['saved_name']){

    $saved_name = $_GET['saved_name'];

    $saved_names[] = $saved_name;        
}
    echo '<pre>', print_r($saved_names, true), '</pre>';
```

Comment: You're only adding one item in this code.  Are you trying to maintain the array in the session and add additional items on subsequent requests?

Comment: Take a look at array_push (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others answers are ok-ish, but i like more this solution, it also check if session is just started (so   `$_SESSION['saved_names']` is not set yet) :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['saved_names'] = isset( $_SESSION['saved_names']) ?  $_SESSION['saved_names'] : [];

if($_GET['saved_name']){
  $_SESSION['saved_names'][] = $_GET['saved_name'];
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($_SESSION['saved_names'], true), '</pre>';
?>
```

**Edit**
@elitepc solution (as he said) is not working because

```
$saved_names = array(); /empty array
$saved_names = $_SESSION['saved_names'];  / <- it has not been declared also will never update
```

And then

```
$saved_name = $_GET['saved_name'];
$saved_names[] = $saved_name;
```

So basically everytime  it just creates an empty array and put inside the `$_GET` value.

You have to check if the session variable it's been initialized and in case update it with `$_GET` value

Comment: ^This worked! I tried the other things, but the problem persisted.. I could never get a length of more than one

Comment: I've updated my answer with an explanation why

Answer (score 3):

```
$_SESSION['saved_names'] = $saved_names;
```

Is this line correct? did you mean

```
$saved_names = $_SESSION['saved_names'];
```

You are resetting the session array and only saving one element, the array will always have length 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();

if($_GET['saved_name']){

    $_SESSION['saved_names'][] = $_GET['saved_name'];
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($_SESSION['saved_names'], true), '</pre>';
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.